# Adaptive logo in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem with the management of the logo. I have the logo which by default is white, when you scroll it changes to black and it works. The problem is that when it becomes responsive the logo always starts with white and having the white navbar is not visible. How can I do so that when it becomes responsive the other logo starts directly.I'm using Bootstrap. thanks a lot

```js
// JavaScript Document
(function($) {
  "use strict";



  // Collapse Navbar 
  var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink")
      $(".logo").attr("src", "https://www.orticaweb.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Twitter-00-Logo-Nero.png");

    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink")
      $(".logo").attr("src", "https://loghi-famosi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Twitter-Logo-650x366.png");

    }
  };
  // Collapse now if page is not at top 
  navbarCollapse();
  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled 
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);






  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing 
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") ==
      this.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ?
        target :
        $("[name=" + this.hash.slice(1) + "]");
      if (target.length) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70,
          },
          1000,
          "easeInOutExpo"
        );
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 200vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
}

#mainNav {
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#mainNav .navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
  color: #303F9F;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:active,
#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  color: #303F9F;
  font-weight: 500;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    color: white;
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link {
    transition: none;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link:active {
    color: #303F9F;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
    background-color: white;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    color: #303F9F;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link {
    color: #303F9F;
    padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.25rem;
    border-bottom: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link:hover {
    color: #7286CC;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .nav-link:active {
    color: #303F9F;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 0.25rem solid #303F9F;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav .link-collapse {
    color: #303F9F;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  #mainNav .link-collapse:hover {
    color: #7286CC;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>



<body>
  <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light amber lighten-4 fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#home"><img class="img-fluid logo" src="https://loghi-famosi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Twitter-Logo-650x366.png" width="50px">Logo Agency</a>


      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">MENU<i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>



      <div id="navbarResponsive" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger link-collapse" href="#">example</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger link-collapse" href="#">example1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger link-collapse" href="#">example2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger link-collapse" href="#">example3</a></li>


        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't easily reproduce cause of the size of the window provided, but I think you are looking for a way to tell if the navbar is already in the state where it's popped out? If so, since you have jQuery running, you can check in the document.ready function if the navbar has the class that makes it responsive using .hasClass(), and then force it out if so.  Is that what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you want to show a black logo on mobile devices? This can be achieved using CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    background: URL('blacklogopath') !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes and on this I agree, the problem is that once I become responsive, if I scroll and then go back up it gives me the white logo by default. This I can't solve, you should destroy the function under a total of px